# linux bash variable inside system call not working

Tags: bash

I'm writing a script to copy my display settings from my user to root, to avoid the X11 problem when running GUIs as sudo (ex. vivado install on remote machine)

the thing is that this works:

```
sudo xauth add $(xauth -f ~theuser/.Xauthority list|tail -1)
```

and this:

```
xauth -f ~theuser/.Xauthority list|tail -1
```

has the output:

```
servername/unix:12  MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1  1ec6eb59738a492928b63451d2c63304
```

But, and here is my problem, I want to create a script so this can be done by any user

x11sudo.sh

```sh
currentUser=$(whoami)
sudo xauth add $(xauth -f ~$currentUser/.Xauthority list|tail -1)
```

but doesn't work.

The issue is in `xauth -f ~$currentUser/.Xauthority list|tail -1` not recognizing the path to .Xauthority

if in the command line I write:

```sh
theuser@servername:~ $ currentUser=$(whoami)
theuser@servername:~ $ echo $currentUser
theuser
theuser@servername:~ $ xauth -f ~$currentUser/.Xauthority list|tail -1
xauth:  error in locking authority file ~theuser/.Xauthority
theuser@servername:~ $
```

I've tried some iterations, adding `echo`, `""`, `''` and others but always the same result, it doesn't like the text string `~theuser/.Xauthority` if it's created with a variable.

Thank you very much

Comment: But, why not just `~/.Xauthority`? `doesn't work.` What happens? `not recognizing the path to .Xauthority` How do you know? Is there any error message?

Comment: `~` processing happens *before* variable expansion. So you can't use `~$theuser` to get the home directory of `$theuser`.

Comment: Why do you think you need a variable for this? The commands inside `$(...)` are executed in your current shell, not the root shell of `sudo`.

Comment: Thank you both(@Barmar & @KamilCuk)! that was the answer and the knowledge of why is not working.

Comment: BTW: Add an `echo` to your commandline, e.g. `echo xauth -f ~$currentUser/...` to find out what actual commandline the shell executes. Also, reduce your problem: You'd find out that this doesn't have anything to do with x11, centos or xauth, it's just bash. The "linux" tag is completely wrong, too, see its description.

Answer (score 0):

Solved and very fast.

As @Kamilcuk and @Barmar answered in the comments, my error was to believe that I had to store the user to use it inside the sudo instruction.

I was not aware that $(...) was executed in my user.

then I only have 1 more question related to the `~` expansion. If instead of getting the current user I passed the user from a variable(argument) how would be the syntax?

Thank you!

Comment: "One more question" doesn't go in an answer -- but I closed the question with a linked duplicate that tells you how you _would_ handle this if you did in fact need to. (Note that the answers range between "not pretty" and "severely insecure"; anything that uses `eval` without also using `printf %q` needs to be treated with extreme skepticism).